# Windows: Keyboard shortcut to view calendar

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, calendar

Is there a keyboard shortcut to bring up the **calendar** in **Windows 7**? I am referring to the calendar that is displayed if you click on the date-time display in the system tray. If that is not possible, is there any trick to display any calendar (with current date highlighted) with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: If you hit Win+B, it would select the tray, then you could use the arrow keys to select the time. I hope then the enter key would bring the calender(can't test now )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any direct way to do this. Instead, I added the **Calendar** gadget in Windows 7 and created a **AutoHotKey** script to show or hide Gadgets (and thus Calendar) whenever needed when a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) was pressed. The AHK script to do this can be found [here](http://www.autohotkey.net/~ashwin/ShowOrHideGadgets.ahk) and more details on it [here](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/windows-7-keyboard-shortcut-to-showhide-gadgets/).

Comment: links are not working, do you have details or working links?

Answer (score 90):

**Windows 11**

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

**Windows 10 (as of Anniversary Update)**

New in Windows 10 Anniversary Update:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

This will pop-open the calendar and pressing it again will close it.

For a full list of windows shortcuts go [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: Windows 11 users: This was updated to `Win`+`N` ([see also](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec))

Comment: Thanks @EvanWondrasek, I updated my answer

Answer (score 11):

#### Keyboad shortcut

You can display the calendar with a combination of three keyboard shortcuts:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow right</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Explanation

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> selects the Windows system tray
- <kbd>Arrow right</kbd> selects the calendar
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> opens the calendar

#### Screenshot

[image: clock]
<sub>Image source: [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/216018/how-to-view-multiple-time-zones-on-the-system-tray-clock-in-windows-8.1/).</sub>

Comment: I think you should update your answer. This does not work in case there are other minified apps appearing in the tray.(This at least does work on windows 10)

Comment: @AdityaGupta: the question is tagged "windows-7" and there it works regardless of how many minified apps there are. For Windows 10 press Win+Alt+D.

Answer (score 3):

Write this AutoHotKey script:

```
!d:: send #t{tab}{tab}{left}{enter}
```

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will open the date/clock window.

If you don't know what Autohotkey is, just google it, download it, open a notepad document, insert the script line and save the file. rename it as filename.ahk. The file logo will become a green H. Double-click it. The logo will appear in the right hand task bar icons, and the script should work. To change the hotkey, exchange `!` for `#`, `^`, or `+` for <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, respectively (or keep `!` for <kbd>Alt</kbd>). And change the letter if you want. Or learn about AHK and do anything you like:)

Comment: For Windows 10, it would be `windows+t, tab, left, enter`. Update: `windows+b, left, enter` to target system tray first, rather than toolbar first.

Comment: Note: alt+d is used for highlight the address bar in explorer windows and most browsers

Answer (score 2):

You can bring up the "Date and Time" window, which comes up when you click on the "Change date and time settings...", with a shortcut key by doing the following:

1. On the desktop (or any folder) right-click an empty location and click "New", then "Shortcut".
2. For the location type `timedate.cpl`. Click "Next", enter any name you prefer. Then click "Finish".
3. Now right-click the new shortcut and select "Properties". In the "Shortcut key:" text box type any key you would like for the shortcut.

[Source](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/display-windows-clock-date-time-desktop-keyboard-shortcut/2924)

Comment: This will bring up the change date and time settings, but the question is just to show the date time box

Answer (score 1):

The suggested shortcut is physically difficult to trigger. So I used PowerToys to use a simpler shortcut. PowerToys is much simpler to use than AutoHotkey if you're just starting out.

Win+C is usually for Cortana, which I don't use, so I have set it to map to the original Win+Alt+D. Now, if I press Win+C, the Calendar opens.

[image: PowerToys shortcut remap window showing the mapping I made]